# Regex for any number of alphanumeric phrases between two '.'

Tags: regex

I'm having a hard time trying to phrase this question correctly when researching solutions, so I thought I would ask here.  I'm trying to validate a field in my UI that a user will enter in a "Java-package" format string.  So a correct example would be "com.my.app.class1".  However, it needs to be the full package path, so I don't want to accept '*' in the string.  I'm trying to find a way to represent this in regex to validate it.  My first thought is to split the string into pieces using a `.` as the delimiter (`var splitArray : any[] = packageInput.split('.')`), then iterating over the array and check for the correct regex.  However, I wanted to know if I could do it all in one regex phrase.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something as simple as `^\w+(\.\w+)*$` will validate strings of the type you've described, as long as they contain alpha, digits, or _.

It matches all of:

```
class1
com.my.class1
com.my.app.class1
com.my.app.sub.class1
```

and doesn't match:

```
com.my.app.*
```